# .Net core 3: The namespace internal does not exist in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Internal

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I have a .Net core 2.1 project that was using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Internal` namespace, specifically `FormattedLogValues` class.

I am now migrating to .Net core 3, I couldn't find a piece of documentation about where to `FormattedLogValues` was moved or what is its replacement.

Even the namespace [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.internal.formattedlogvalues) is removed

Any tips?

Comment: It's been made [internal](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/pull/513), as the namespace name probably gave away. Whatever you did with it will have to be done without it (probably replacing it with something interface-compatible with `IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`).

Comment: Have you seen this: [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0)?

Comment: Have a look at these GitHub issues, [here](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow/issues/337) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow/pull/338). They are related to Azure, but covers your topic. You can try to update your nuget packages at least (you haven't specified any of them in your question)

Comment: Looking at the source code it looks like the type is still there (under a different namespace) https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Logging/Logging.Abstractions/src/FormattedLogValues.cs but is an internal class now (which is proably why you can't use it - how are you trying to use it out of curiosity?

Answer (score 14):

I fixed the problem by updating `moq` to "4.13.1" and taking advantage of `It.IsAnyType`.

```java
_logger.Verify(f => f.Log(
    It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
    It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
    It.IsAny<Exception>(),
    (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>) It.IsAny<object>()));
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with MOQ? How does this answer relate to the question asked?

Comment: Otherwise why we need to use `FormattedLogValues `?

Comment: The OP stated that they were using it in the previous version .net-core. which had that type available till it was made internal with the update.

Comment: @Nkosi I see. I'm sorry

Comment: I am really surprised by the upvotes :D I really don't see how this answer relates to my question, anyway happy this answer helps others

Comment: Hi Yahya Hussein, Did you solve the problem? I'm in the same problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63960304/formattedlogvalues-is-not-accessible-when-migrating-from-netcore-2-2-to-3-1?noredirect=1#comment113104095_63960304

Comment: The reason why people are associating your question to Moq is possibly because they are  trying to Moq ILogger with strict mock behaviour, thus forcing the creation of the specific Log signature with FormattedLogValues in it, which in  turn has restricted access. Same applies for Rhino strict mode

Answer (score 6):

This really depends on what you are doing with the type, but looking at the code in the [github source](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Logging/Logging.Abstractions/src/FormattedLogValues.cs) it looks like the type still exists, but is internal - which means tht only the library itself can actually access the type, unless you've got the assembly `InternalsVisibleTo("")` - but we'll ignore that for now.

So the type itself in is an implementation of `IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` which is a bit of a weird one but means that if you are testing values going into the logger you can access then like so:

`logger.State[0][0].Value`

"State" here is what is defined in the library so the terminology is hopefully familiar.

If you are using Moq or equivilent, you could probably use:

```
_logger.Verify(f => f.Log(
    It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
    It.IsAny<IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>>(),
    It.IsAny<Exception>(),
    (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>) It.IsAny<object>()));
```

If you want to use it in your own logger you would have to create your own class that inherits from the class:

```
public class MyLogValues : IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>> {}
```

Then both classes can be reduced down to the interface

Hopefully this helps, I think it depends on what exactly you are using the type *for*.

Answer (score 1):

As previous answers pointed out, you must use `It.IsAnyType` or `It.IsValueType`.

So setup would look like this:

```
mock.Setup(_ => _.Log(
  It.IsNotNull<LogLevel>(), 
  It.IsNotNull<EventId>(),
  It.IsAny<It.IsValueType>(),
  It.IsNotNull<Exception>(),
  (Func<It.IsValueType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>());
```

Ps. **DO NOT** forget to cast the last parameter.

If you also need to check parameters passed to the method you must use `InvocationAction`:

```
mock.Callback(new InvocationAction((invocation) => {
  Assert.AreEqual(level, invocation.Arguments[0]);
  Assert.AreEqual(exception, invocation.Arguments[3]);
}));
```